# Target Data is missing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I made a model using mixed precision training, and I came across this error. I searched a while but couldn't find anything. Here is where the error happened :

```
history_101_food_classes_feature_extract = model.fit(x=train_data,
                                                     epochs=3,
                                                     steps_per_epoch=(len(train_data)),
                                                     validation_data=test_data,
                                                     validation_steps=int(0.15 * len(test_data)),
                                                     callbacks=[create_tensorboard_callback("training_logs", 
                                                                                            "efficientnetb0_101_classes_all_data_feature_extract"),
                                                                model_checkpoint])
```

The error I get is : `ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy, and therefore expects target data to be provided in 'fit()'.`

Here's the compiling of the model :

```
from keras import layers
from keras import preprocessing

input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
base_model = keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_layer")

x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(len(class_names))(x)
outputs = layers.Activation("softmax", dtype=tf.float32, name="softmax_float32")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

#compiling
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I googled the problem, and did some research, but none of it was relevant to my case. I tried adding `x=train_data` (instead of just `train_data`), in case it was mixed up with the output, but it didn't work. The documentation said to leave a y value blank if it's a dataset, which I did. Adding y value gives a different error, that there shouldn't be one.

Comment: You need to clearly specify how you defined train_data.

Comment: `train_data = train_data.map(map_func=preprocess_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`

and `train_data = train_data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(batch_size=32).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`

Comment: That is not useful, you need to add the full definition of how the training data is loaded. The problem is that likely you did not include target values in the dataset.

Answer (score -1):

You have add target or y variable to the fit function. Here i mentioned terget_data in the below fit function.

```
history_101_food_classes_feature_extract = model.fit(x=train_data,
                                             **y=target_data,**                                               

epochs=3,

                                             

                                           steps_per_epoch=len(train_data)),
                                             validation_data=test_data,
                                             validation_steps=int(0.15 * l 
                                             en(test_data)),
                                             callbacks 
                               [create_tensorboard_callback("training_logs",                                                                                          
                     "efficientnetb0_101_classes_all_data_feature_extract"),                                                               
                                                          model_checkpoint])
```

Comment: No, this is not the right answer, as a tf.Dataset is being used which should contain the x and y variables inside, but the OP has not provided enough information to check for this. Adding a y variable in model.fit while using a tf.Dataset will result in an error.